# Detect and block UIWebView redirection by iOS API

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am using an API in my iOS app that gives some info about user.
If user is not logged in, the API opens the login page otherwise returns the user info that I can display on UI.

In my app, I want to implement a text label and a button.

If user is logged-in, the app should display the button, asking to login.
Otherwise the button will be hidden and text label will show user info.

The issue is that, for both login and to get user info, the same API is provided.

For deciding to display the button, I need to prevent the API from opening the webview on it's own, and only do it when user presses the button in my app.

Is there a way to detect that the API is trying to open webview and then block it?

Comment: API opening the webview? Did not understand that part.

Comment: If API detects the user is not logged in, it redirects to login page in SFSafariViewController.